# How to instantiate a File object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, file, initialization

I see that my IDE recognizes `File` as a Typescript object. Doing a [refined search in Google](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&ei=WZ59XMGMH4TL-gSr3ZXYBg&q=site%3Atypescriptlang.org%20File%20object&oq=site%3Atypescriptlang.org%20File%20object&gs_l=psy-ab.3...193722.193722..194239...0.0..0.218.218.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.FLtz8SF6ciQ) brings me to [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html), which has nothing about `File` objects. `File` is neither in [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) or in [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Are `File` objects in Typescript handled [exactly the same way as in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)? Are there any breaking differences?

Again, how to instantiate a File type in Typescript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `File` class is not defined as part of the TypeScript language proper, but rather is a part of the DOM specification. TypeScript provides a standard declaration file for DOM objects as part of the stdlib, which you can view for yourself [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5201-L5210):

```
/** The File interface provides information about files and allows JavaScript in a web page to access their content. */
interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModified: number;
    readonly name: string;
}

declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag): File;
};
```

Of course the declaration file itself isn't very user friendly. You'll probably find the [MDN DOM API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) more useful (though note, it's for JavaScript, not TypeScript, so don't expect any explicit type annotations). It provides this example:

```
var file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
```

And although this is technically JavaScript, it will compile just fine as TypeScript, and the inferred type of `file` will be `File`.

Comment: since its an interface, you can instantiate it (if you're binding it in an input-file) with `const file: File = {} as File`

Comment: @KarlAnthonyBaluyot `as File` doesn't actually instantiate anything; it's merely a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). `const file: File = {} as File` will compile, but it's not type safe and `file.name` will be `undefined`.